# Does AWS EMR has resource manager in HA?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop-yarn, emr

I would like to know how I can turn on HA for resource manager in AWS EMR . Similarly how I can have secondary name node on EMR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon EMR does not support HA for the YARN resource manager. If the master goes down the cluster will be terminated. Since there is only one master node, there is only be one namenode.